# What is the easiest way to access SVN history in a different branch using Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, branch, subclipse

My team is supporting a small Java development team that had been working on a development branch with Eclipse and Subclipse. We've been periodically merging their changes associated with appropriate tasks and defects from this development branch to a release branch which eventually gets merged into a trunk that represents production. Based on best practices advice from CollabNet, we recently created a new development branch from the trunk and moved the old development branch to an archive directory. (The motivation for this is that eventually changes would accumulate in the development branch that never get merged anywhere else, and the development branch would become impractically different from the release branches and the trunk.)

Our java team was disappointed to discover that once they'd created their new Eclipse workspaces with the new development branch, file histories in Subclipse did not show all of their individual changes. Only the merge operations are listed. This makes sense since the new development branch was copied from trunk, which only ever had these merges performed on it.

But our Java team would like to easily reference the histories in the old development branch. What is the easiest way for them to do this? Some options I can think of are:

1. Navigate to the old branch in the SVN Repository Exploring perspective and examine file histories there. This involves lots of clicking through the repository hierarchy, especially to an individual source file. Is there a way to enter a path in this perspective and jump to it? Or is the only way to click through the hierarchy?
2. Maintain a separate Eclipse workspace with the old development branch. This means switching workspaces to see the individual developer histories. And it's easy to forget which workspace you're in.
3. Use Team -> Switch to temporarily switch the file or project to the old branch in your same workspace. Then view the history of the switched file(s). It's easy to forget what you've switched, which can lead to committing to the wrong branch.

Also, none of these options make it easy to compare what's in the new branch to what's in the old branch.

Are there any easier ways I'm missing? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Do you know a command line for e.g. `svn log` that will produce the result you expect? I guess that it could be easier to help you if there is a command line that works for you and you want to obtain the same result in the IDE. It will be easier to understand what log output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to follow best practices then you should look at trunk-based development.  https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com

There is an option with svn log to show the original commits for a merge.  This is the -g option when using the command line.  In Subclipse, it is a checkbox on the History view.  "Include Merged revisions".  This will then expand the merges to show what was merged.  Same option exists on Blame.  It will make these operations take considerably longer to run in many cases.

The only way to fix this is to use a better process.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The "Include Merged Revisions" checkbox unfortunately is not showing me the changes in the old branch I was hoping to see. I'll start looking into the trunk-based development approach to branching you recommend.